# Add custom class object to Apache Storm Config

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have created a custom class called Configuration.java and I want to put that into my Config object within my storm topology. When I try my topology I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topology conf is not json-serializable
```

Here is my code that is trying to put the Configuration object into Config

```java
public static Config loadConf(String resource) {

        Configuration _epconf = null;
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.registerSerialization(Configuration.class);  //register the Configuration class 

        try {

           //load the yaml file into the Configuration pojo
           _epconf = (Configuration)yaml.loadAs(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(resource)), Configuration.class);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.error("Configuration file does not exist : " + resource);
            System.err.println("Conf file does not exist : " + resource);
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (YAMLException e ) {
            Log.error("Error parsing YAML file for configuration : " + resource + "\n" + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Error parsing YAML file for configuration : " + resource);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        //verify object is not empty
        if (_epconf == null) {
            Log.error("Empty configuration object created from : " + resource );
            System.err.println("Empty configuration object created from : " + resource);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        conf.put("epconf", _epconf);  //add the Configuration to the Config object

        return conf;
    }
```

I believe the issue is that I am not properly registering my class for Serialization. I suspect conf.registerSerialization(Configuration.class) is not completely correct, but I am not able to follow what the documentation on the storm homepage is asking for other than that.

Comment: Are you trying to specify a different configuration class?  why not just add additional properties to the usual class?

Comment: @Chris Gerken Well I tried to add the properties individually, but I kept getting the same json-serialization error.

Comment: Who is going to use the properties? and what type(s) are the values?